Unable to start the daemon process - fatal error: DEBUG MESSAGE: unimplemented bytecode
What happened here and how to recover?
Clearing the gradle cache doesn't seem to help.
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.For more details on the daemon, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html in the Gradle documentation.
Process command line: /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx1g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /home/jakub/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.9-bin/90cnw93cvbtalezasaz0blq0a/gradle-8.9/lib/gradle-daemon-main-8.9.jar -javaagent:/home/jakub/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.9-bin/90cnw93cvbtalezasaz0blq0a/gradle-8.9/lib/agents/gradle-instrumentation-agent-8.9.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 8.9
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (macroAssembler_x86.cpp:829), pid=1970719, tid=1970722
#  fatal error: DEBUG MESSAGE: unimplemented bytecode
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (21.0.4+7) (build 21.0.4+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu222.04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (21.0.4+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu222.04, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xbe3e05]  MacroAssembler::debug64(char*, long, long*)+0x45
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /home/jakub/.gradle/daemon/8.9/core.1970719)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/jakub/.gradle/daemon/8.9/hs_err_pid1970719.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-21
#

-----------------------
Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:
 - gradle.properties in project root directory


Restarting the machine seems to fix it. But where was this "unimplemented bytecode" coming from?
